# Android : Merging/concatenating two audio files hangs up the application

Tags: android, performance, merge, audio-recording, mp4parser

I'm appending two audio file using mp4parser. Appending is done but it is very slow don't know what is the issue.

On this line debugger stuck for big audio files for example approx 30 minutes audio file.

### Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);

Here is code.

```
Movie[] inMovies = null;
                inMovies = new Movie[]{
                        MovieCreator.build(fileOne),
                        MovieCreator.build(fileTwo)};
                List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();

                for (Movie m : inMovies) {
                    for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
                        if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                            audioTracks.add(t);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Movie result = new Movie();
                if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {
                    result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
                }
                Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);
                String fileName = getFilename();
                FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(String.format(fileName), "rw").getChannel();
                out.writeContainer(fc);
                fc.close();
```

Manifestfile

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ehrlite"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ehr_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.webservice.myApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ehrlite.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ehrlite.MasterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.ehrlite.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ehrlite.PrevMemo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webviewcall.WebViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>`enter code here`
        <activity
            android:name="com.ehrlite.TranscribedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone help me out to improve performance,
thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put your manifests?

Comment: @BhunnuBaba I have updated my question.

Comment: perhaps MyApplication file extends with MultiDexApplication if yes then once  add  android:largeHeap="true" in application tag

Comment: @BhunnuBaba I have tried but not getting success...

Comment: once try with separate thread

Comment: @BhunnuBaba Tried but debugger still stuck on this line new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result)...

Comment: I was having the same problem. but if you do not put it on debug it runs fine. that said you should not put it on main thread as bigger files may take longer time to process. I put few logs instead of debugging for a work around. this problem is rather general, CPU intensive task runs slow when you put the process on debug.

Comment: Checkd this different approach ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731155/how-to-merge-two-mp3-files-into-one-combine-join    Or with library like https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/AppendExample.java

Comment: Guys any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for your answer.
I was faced issue previously.
You are using `RandomAccessfile`. You need to use `FileOutputStream`

```
Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);
        String outputFilePath = getfilename();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFilePath));
        out.writeContainer(fos.getChannel());
        fos.close();
```

Reference:

[why are java RandomAccessFile so much slower than FileOutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350269/why-are-java-randomaccessfile-so-much-slower-than-fileoutputstream)

Comment: I have tried FileOutputStream inplace of RandomAccessfile but still it takes much time for concatenating two audio files. No Success.

Comment: do one thing. there may is a chance to didn't find proper path for getFilename().
Use hardcoded path for this

Comment: @NovusMobile great observation for code. Bhumit You should try this .Thanks for sharing. I was facing same issue. +1 for this.