# Async Log4J2 and logrotate not working correctly (truncate is broken)

Tags: java, log4j2, logrotate

I am using Log4J2 async logger to log my Java application and I'm using `logrotate` to store the old logs everyday.

Previously, I was using Log4J2 synchronously and everything worked fine; since I switched to async logging `logrotate` stopped working correctly.

I think I am experiencing the same issue explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/221337/logrotate-successful-original-file-goes-back-to-original-size): since I am using the `copytruncate` option, the old log file gets truncated after being copied, but the logger doesn't know it, so it continues writing starting from the "old" index, thus filling all the previous space in the file with `NUL` values, which is exactly what I'm seeing.

This is the command I am launching my application with:

```
java -Dlog4j2.contextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector -Dlog4j2.asyncQueueFullPolicy=Discard -Dlog4j2.asyncLoggerRingBufferSize=6553600 -Djava.library.path=my_libs -cp MyApplication.jar:my_libs/* com.gscaparrotti.Main >> logs/other.log
```

This is an excerpt from my `log4j2.xml` file:

```
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <RandomAccessFile name="LogToFile" fileName="logs/standalone.log" append="true" ImmediateFlush="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>[MyApp - %t - %d{DATE}] %5p %c{1} - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RandomAccessFile>
        <RandomAccessFile name="LogAnalyzer" fileName="logs/analyzer.txt" append="true" ImmediateFlush="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>[%d{DATE}] %5p %c{1} - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="analyzer" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogAnalyzer"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is the `logrotate` configuration I'm using (it's the same for all the log files):

```
/root/logs/analyzer.txt {
  copytruncate
  daily
  rotate 4
  compress
  missingok
  create 640 root root
}
```

A sort-of solution would be to stop my application before `logrotate`ing it, but this is hardly a good solution, since I'd like to have it running.

What else could I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the `RandomAccessFileAppender` with a simple `FileAppender`.

Your issue is not caused by the use of asynchronous loggers, but by the appender you use:

- Java's [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), which is used by the `RandomAccessFileAppender` opens files in read/write mode **without** the `O_APPEND` option (cf. [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)),
- [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), which is used by the usual `FileAppender`, opens files in write only mode **with** the `O_APPEND` option.

The presence or the absence of this option influences how writes are performed:

> **O_APPEND**
> The file is opened in append mode.  Before each `write(2)`,
> the file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as
> if with `lseek(2)`.  The modification of the file offset and
> the write operation are performed as a single atomic step.

(from [man open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)).

When you truncate your log file a `FileAppender`s offset will be reset to 0, while a `RandomAccessFileAppender` will continue writing at the previous position.

**Remark:** Log4j also provides a [`RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender), which will remove the need to use **logrotate** at all.

**Edit**: the exact options used to create the objects used by the managers can be found:

- for the `FileManager` in [`FileManagerFactory#createManager`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/5f37d176f706c33132e5316a4bc7099644ce8ac1/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/FileManager.java#L438),
- for the `RandomAccessFileManager` in [`RandomAccessFileManagerFactory#createManager`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/5f37d176f706c33132e5316a4bc7099644ce8ac1/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/RandomAccessFileManager.java#L208).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is some performance drawback using `FileAppender` instead of `RandomFileAppender`?

Comment: Also, from the question on Server Fault I linked in my question, I was wondering if the `O_APPEND` option could be the issue, but on the Javadoc I couldn't find an explicit reference to the options used by `RandomAccessFile` and `FileOutputStream`. Where did you find this information?

Comment: @gscaparrotti: there is some performance testing code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6350269/11748454). I updated the answer with links to the source code, where the `RandomAccessFile` and `FileOutputStream` are created.